# How to set a buffer locally face attribute for a particular buffer?

Tags: emacs, customization, font-face, org-mode, emacs-faces

I want to change the face attribute in Org-Agenda buffer only.
So I need to change Org-Agenda face attribute **buffer locally**.

Here is my code: (which is globally)

```
(defun my-org-agenda-hl-line ()
  (hl-line-mode)
  (set-face-attribute 'hl-line nil
                  :box '(:color "deep pink" :line-width 2))
)
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'my-org-agenda-hl-line)
```

Please to help me make this buffer locally. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

```
;; First create new face which is a copy of hl-line-face
(copy-face 'hl-line 'hl-line-agenda-face)

;; Change what you want in this new face 
(set-face-attribute 'hl-line-agenda-face nil
                    :box '(:color "deep pink" :line-width 2))

;; The function to use the new face
(defun my-org-agenda-hl-line ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'hl-line-face) ; This is how to make it local
       'hl-line-agenda-face)
    (hl-line-mode))

;; Finally, the hook
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'my-org-agenda-hl-line)
```

Comment: Since Emacs 23.1, the other answer by Wenpin CHOU is the recommended way, namely use ``face-remap-add-relative``. // This is a nice answer that I should upvote. Once CHOU's answer gets enough votes, I'd upvote this one, too. ;-p

Answer (score 4):

try [face-remap-add-relative](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html).

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (hl-line-mode)
            (face-remap-add-relative 'hl-line :box '(:color "deep pink" :line-width 2))))
```

also, see [How to modify-face for a specific buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-modify-face-for-a-specific-buffer)